# update profile in laravel API for mobile apps

Tags: laravel, edit, profile

I want to build an api for mobile apps. for now, i want to create an edit profile api. but i dont know how to store an image, if user wants to upload their avatar.
Here is my code:

```
public function profileedit($id, Request $request){
      $users = user::find($id);
      $users->name = $request->firstName;
      $users->thumbnail = $request->avatar;
      $users->save();

      $data[] = [
        'id'=>$users->uid,
        'name'=>$users->name,
        'avatar'=>$users->thumbnail,
        'status'=>200,
      ];
      return response()->json($data);

    }
```

how to put the $request->avatar into my project storage, and show it in url form (my project is already uploaded on the server)

Comment: You should use another service to store the image and get a link. for example of services `AWS S3` https://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to store files in Laravel is this.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function profileedit($id, Request $request){

  //validator place

  $users = user::find($id);
  $users->name = $request->firstName;
  $users->thumbnail = $request->avatar->store('avatars','public');
  $users->save();

  $data[] = [
    'id'=>$users->uid,
    'name'=>$users->name,
    'avatar'=>Storage::url($users->thumbnail),
    'status'=>200,
  ];
  return response()->json($data);

}
```

but as you probably know, you should run `php artisan storage:link` command to generate storage shortcut in public directory.

for security reason you can use validator to let only image file store. in this example I limited file to all image types with maximum 4MB size

```
$request->validate([
    'avatar' => 'required|image|max:4096',
]);
```

for more information these are document links.

[File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem)

[Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#validating-arrays)